# How to manage long list of languages in resources folder

Tags: android, android-location

My applications is going to support over 37 languages and I have to provide local strings for each language. I know that we can support different languages by providing separate files in /res/values-xx folder, however the problem is managing over 37 different folders. If I have to add a folder for each language, it will be a long list of values-xx in my res folder.

Is there any other way where I can group /res/values folders such as /res/values/values-xx (or something). Any suggestion would be helpful.

Thanks
Bsengar

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your project will have to contain all these folders, but you can have them generated from a more maintainable source like excel file with 38 columns.

Comment: are you shure MS-Excel is MORE maintainable??

Comment: @RafaelT In some cases yes. If you have translators that know how to use it. In excel you can put screenshots where each text is used. This can also help them make correct translations. Also you have the ability to generate strings.xml for Android android Localizable.strings for iOS. Of course there might be a better tool for that, but I haven't used any.